# http_post_fields() couldn't resolve host name

Tags: php, http, curl, pecl

My PHP script uses http_post_fields() to make a post request to another server.
Here is an example of the code:

```
$g = http_post_fields("http://mysite.com", $some_array);
```

Though the script occasionally works, I often get this error:

```
 http_post_fields() [function.http-post-fields]: couldn't resolve host name; name lookup timed out
```

I have now tried a variety of http addresses in the function, they all result in this error.
Does anyone know what the source of my trouble is?

Comment: Sounds as DNS related problem with your web server. What kind of server environment are you on?

Comment: Intermittent DNS failures can either be an overloaded router dropping the UDP packets, or possibly a response which is too large, causing a TCP connection to be used instead which is blocked at a firewall somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the input Kasun. In the end, I got tired of this PECL library (where http_post_fields is defined) and I used cURL instead.  The goal I'm reaching for here, is to request a security ticket from 1 server to another.  Of course, the whole module works smoothly, now that I'm using cURL.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ssh access, try this command on shell `ping mysite.com` and see if you get any response

There can be firewall/proxy server configuration to prevent sending POST request from the server

try this and check domain resolve to IP.

```
<?php
$ip = gethostbyname('www.example.com');

echo $ip;
?>
```

Example with HTTPRequest which will echo status code

```
<?php
$r = new HttpRequest('http://www.example.com/', HttpRequest::METH_POST);
$r->addPostFields(array('param1' => 'value'));

try {
   $http_req->send();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {

}

$response_code = $http_req->getResponseCode();
 echo $response_code;
?>
```

Comment: Okay. SSH'd into the server ping'd the remote server. 0% loss. they can communicate.  I copied your function into my script and called it passing in target server & port as parameters- total success.

Comment: * edit- The communication is successful, though the function call in my original script still fails.

Comment: I just tried the method new httpRequest..
it returned this error `HttpInvalidParamException' with message Empty or too short HTTP message:'' in /var/www/vhosts/mySite.ca/httpdocs/portal1/application/views/applications/grid/auth_sample.php:0 inner exception 'HttpRequestException' with message 'couldn't resolve host name; name lookup timed out (http://mysite.com/)`