# File permissions error with http_post in my php setup

Tags: php, http-post

I am trying to send an http_post_fields to a server:

```
 $emailAddress = "email@email.com";
 $emailPassword = "password";
 $post = array ('cmd' => 'cmd_user_login',
                'lcmd' => 'user_delete',
                'show' => 'simple_msg.xml',
                'username' => 'uName',
                'password' => 'uPassword',
                'lusername' => $emailAddress,
                'lpassword' => $emailPassword,
                'uid' => $emailAddress);
 $result = http_post_fields('https://1.2.3.4:7443/cgi/user.cgi',$post);
```

I am getting the following error in my http error_logs when I try to run this page in a browser:

```
PHP Warning:  http_post_fields(): Couldn't connect to server; 
Failed to connect to 1.2.3.4:Permission denied
```

If I try to run this script from command line, it works fine.
It seems to be there is a file permissions problem somewhere within my php setup, how do I begin to solve this?

Comment: Is it an authorization issue with the script or in an .htaccess?  May need to set some additional [options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.request.options.php)

Comment: the request isn't leaving my server.  tcpdump showed no data outbound,  tcpdump on the remote server showed no data inbound.  It appears to me that the script is failing because php can't access the function to process the http_post request...

Comment: possible duplicate of [http\_post\_fields() couldn't resolve host name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864381/http-post-fields-couldnt-resolve-host-name)

Comment: not a duplicate.  errors are completely different.  I found the problem, SELinux.

Answer (score 0):

SELinux was preventing the http_post from occuring.